# Direct Generic Exceptions

Tags: java, exception, generics

My question is a follow-up to this question:

[Why doesn't Java allow generic subclasses of Throwable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501277/why-doesnt-java-allow-generic-subclasses-of-throwable)

The question was answered perfectly, but only on *indirect* generic exception, that's:

```
public class MyException<T> extends Exception {
```

What was left void, is *direct* generics:

```
public static <T extends Exception> void checkForException(Class<T> exType) {

    try {
        // some code
    } catch (T e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

### Why is this not allowed?

Though, the only reason I could think this is not allowed, is that `T` could be a type, that is also explicitly caught:

```
// if T is IOException
catch(T e) { }
catch(IOException e) { }
```

But is this a good reason to block it?
 The same effect, could as well be done without generics too:

```
catch(Exception e) { }
catch(IOException e { }
```

---

Here's the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#cannotCatch) of the above restriction.

Comment: It's not possible to check if the exception is instance of `T` in runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in Java Type Variables, i.e. **T**, are [not reifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18848885/why-following-types-are-reifiable-non-reifiable-in-java) due to *[Type Erasure](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ101)*.

This means the compiler does not have **T** at runtime at all.

Hence there is no way that catch block of yours will ever know what **T** originally was.  And no, you can't just treat it as the base type.  That would do something completely different.  What if you had

```
catch(T e) { }
catch(MyBaseException e) { }
catch(MyApplicationException e) { }
```

and **T** extends *MyBaseException*.  See how that got really bad really quick?

Read more in the excellent [Java Generics FAQs - Under The Hood Of The Compiler](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html)

Personally I've never liked type erasure, but the language designers swore they had their reasons for using it.  So here we are.

Comment: Well, for backwards-compabilty.

Answer (score 0):

If our exception type is generic, we don't know the actual type at compile time, and at runtime, the type is erased. *`throw`ing* such an exception is possible because the `Class<T>` allows us to construct an instance, but *`catch`ing* must know the type to match at compile time. However it cannot know the type, because it's not specified at the catch site.