# throws x extends Exception method signature

Tags: java, exception, generics

Reading the JavaDoc of [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow-java.util.function.Supplier-), I bumped in a weird method signature; I never saw in my life:

```
public <X extends Throwable> T orElseThrow(Supplier<? extends X> exceptionSupplier)
                                throws X extends Throwable
```

At first glance, I wondered how the generic exception `<X extends Throwable>` is even possible, since you can't do that ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501277/why-doesnt-java-allow-generic-subclasses-of-throwable), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30643677/direct-generic-exceptions)). On second thought, this starts to make sense, as it is here just to bind the `Supplier`... but the supplier itself knows exactly what type it should be, before generics.

But the second line hit me:

- `throws X` is a complete generic exception type.

And then:

- `X extends Throwable`, what in the world does *this* mean?

  - `X` is already bound in the method signature.
- Will this by any means, solve the generic exception restriction?
- Why not just `throws Throwable`, as the rest will be erased by type erasure?

---

And one, not directly related question:

- Will this method be required to be caught as `catch(Throwable t)`, or by the provided `Supplier`'s type; since it can't be checked for at runtime?

Comment: You can't have generic `Exception` types, but you can bind `Exception` types to generic parameters.

Comment: Also, that isn't a source code declaration, it's some bastardization (of the bounds) in the javadoc.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I pointed that out, already.

Comment: Source is here  http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Optional.java#Optional.orElseThrow%28java.util.function.Supplier%29

Comment: @MouseEvent Please don't keep adding questions to your original question that make answers incomplete / invalid

Comment: It is allowed to have a type parameter to subclass throwable. What is to have a generic exception `MyException<T> extends Throwable`. (Your links dont say that either).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Treat it like any other generic code you've read.

Here's the formal signature from what I see in [Java 8's source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Optional.java#Optional.orElseThrow%28java.util.function.Supplier%29):

```
public <X extends Throwable> T orElseThrow(Supplier<? extends X> exceptionSupplier) throws X
```

- `X` has an upper bound of `Throwable`.  This will be important later on.
- We return a type `T` which is bound to `Optional`'s `T`
- We expect a `Supplier` which has a wildcard upper bound of `X`
- We throw `X` (which is valid, since `X` has an upper bound of `Throwable`).  This is specified in [JLS 8.4.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.6); so long as `X` is seen as a subtype of `Throwable`, its declaration is valid and legal here.

[There is an open bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8077565) about the Javadoc being misleading.  In this case, it's best to trust the source code as opposed to the documentation until the bug is declared fixed.

As for why we're using `throws X` instead of `throws Throwable`:  `X` is guaranteed to be bound to `Throwable` in the uppermost bounds.  If you want a more specific `Throwable` (runtime, checked, or `Error`), then merely throwing `Throwable` wouldn't give you that flexibility.

To your last question:

> Will this method be required to be caught in a catch(Throwable t) clause?

*Something* down the chain has to handle the exception, be that a `try...catch` block or the JVM itself. Ideally, one would want to create a `Supplier` bound to an exception that best conveyed their needs.  You don't have to (and probably should ***not***) create a `catch(Throwable t)` for this case; if your `Supplier` is type bound to a specific exception that you need to handle, then it's best to use that as your `catch` later up in the chain.

Comment: I made a minor typo in my last bullet, please review it.

Comment: And added another question, thereafter.

Comment: Be **careful** about adding more than one question to a question.  I've addressed the earlier concern, and I'll be happy to review the revised bullet, but the second question is overreaching.  I'll add that part in a bit later.

Comment: For your last paragraph, How can I _want_ a more specific `Throwable`, do you mean by subclassing? Note that `Optional` is declared final.

Comment: Your `Supplier` instance is providing the exception you want to throw to begin with; if that's type bound to something more specific like `NullPointerException`, you'd want to use that instead of `Throwable`.  Or better yet - if you decided to throw an `Error` at this point, you would rather throw the `Error` than `Throwable`.

Comment: This means, that a method that calls this, may `catch` it just with a `NullPointerException`? This is actually my last question.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstood, but can __this method itself__ be caught more specificly? If not why shouldn't I say `throws Throwable`? The only place this makes sense to me, is when overrided, but as I pointed out, `Optional` is `final`. (I keep on editing my last question, as it seems to mislead, sorry).

Comment: Understand two things:  `X` dictates what we are going to throw, and `Supplier<? extends X>` specifies *what* that particular something is that we're going to throw.  If your Supplier instance provides a specific type of exception, then that is to be caught as opposed to `Throwable`.

Comment: @MouseEvent Yes, with the throws beeing typed to the return type of the supplier, the following method requires (and allows) a specific "`catch (InterruptedException)`": `opt.orElseThrow(()->new InterruptedException());`. It is independent of the type of opt (e.g. `Optional<Integer> opt = new Optional<>();`)

Answer (score 11):

The Javadoc's method signature is **different than the source code.** According to the [b132 source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Optional.java#Optional.orElseThrow%28java.util.function.Supplier%29):

```
public <X extends Throwable> T orElseThrow(Supplier<? extends X> exceptionSupplier)
              throws X {  // Added by me: See? No X extends Throwable
    if (value != null) {
        return value;
    } else {
        throw exceptionSupplier.get();
    }
}
```

**Confirmed:** This is an issue with the Javadoc generation. As a test, I created a new project and generated Javadoc for the following class:

```
package com.stackoverflow.test;

public class TestJavadoc {
    public static <X extends Throwable> void doSomething() throws X {

    }
}
```

This is the resulting Javadoc:

[image: Javadoc Screenshot]

**Double confirmed:** There is an [open bug about the Javadoc for this class](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8077565)

Answer (score 8):

Java cannot catch generic exception types due to erasure

```
    catch(FooException<Bar> e)        --analogy->        o instanceof List<String>
```

`catch` and `instanceof` depend on runtime type information; erasure ruins that.

However, it's a little too harsh to forbid generic declaration of exception types like `FooException<T>`. Java could allow it; just require that only raw type and wildcard type are allowed in `catch`

```
    catch(FooException e)              --analogy->       o instanceof List
    catch(FooException<?> e)                             o instanceof List<?>
```

An argument can be made that, the type of an exception is mostly interested by catch clauses; if we cannot catch generic exception types, there's no point of having them in the first place. OK.

---

Now, we cannot do this either

```
    catch(X e)   // X is a type variable
```

then why does Java allow `X` to be thrown in the first place?

```
    ... foo() throws X
```

As we'll see later, this construct, aided by erasure, could actually subvert the type system.

Well, this feature is quite useful though - at least conceptually. We write generic methods so that we can write template code for unknown input and return types; same logic for throw types! For example

```
    <X extends Exception> void logAndThrow(X ex) throws X
        ...
        throw ex;

    ...
    (IOException e){   
        logAndThrow(e);   // throws IOException
```

We need to able to throw generically to achieve exception transparency when abstracting a block of code. Another example, say we are tired of writing this kind of boilerplate repeatedly

```
    lock.lock();
    try{ 
        CODE
    }finally{
        lock.unlock();
    }
```

and we want a wrapper method for that, taking in a lambda for the CODE

```
    Util.withLock(lock, ()->{ CODE });
```

The problem is, CODE could throw any exception type; the original boilerplate throws whatever CODE throws; and we want the `writeLock()` expression to do the same, i.e. exception transparency. Solution -

```
    interface Code<X extends Throwable>
    {
        void run() throws X;
    }



    <X extends Throwable> void withLock(Lock lock, Code<X> code) throws X
        ...
        code.run();  // throws X

    ...
    withLock(lock, ()->{ throws new FooException(); });  // throws FooException
```

This only matters for checked exceptions. Unchecked exceptions can propagate freely anyways.

One serious flaw of the `throws X` approach is that it doesn't work well with 2 or more exception types.

---

All right, that's really nice. But we are not seeing any of such usages in new JDK APIs. No functional types of any method parameter can throw any checked exception. If you do `Stream.map(x->{ BODY })`, `BODY` cannot throw any checked exceptions. They really really hate checked exceptions with lambdas.

Another example is `CompletableFuture`, where exception is a central part of the whole concept; yet, no checked exceptions are allowed either in lambda bodies.

If you are a dreamer, you might believe that in some future version of Java, an elegant mechanism of exception transparency for lambda will be invented, nothing like this ugly `throws X` hack; therefore we don't need to pollute our APIs with `<X>`s for now. Yeah, dream on, man.

---

So, how much is `throws X` used anyways?

Throughout the entire JDK source, the only public API that does that is `Optional.orElseThrow()` (and its cousins `OptionalInt/Long/Double`). That's it.

(There's a shortcoming with the `orElseGet/orElseThrow` design - the decision of branching cannot be done in the lambda body. We could instead design a more general method

```
    T orElse( lambda ) throws X

    optional.orElse( ()->{ return x; } );
    optional.orElse( ()->{ throw ex; } );
    optional.orElse( ()->{ if(..)return x; else throw ex; } );
```

Besides `orElseThrow`, the only other method in JDK that `throws X` is the non-public `ForkJoinTask.uncheckedThrow()`. It is used for "sneaky throw", i.e. a code can throw a checked exception, without the compiler and runtime knowing about it -

```
    void foo() // no checked exception declared in throws
    {
        throw sneakyThrow( new IOExcepiton() ); 
    }
```

here, `IOException` is thrown from `foo()` at runtime; yet the compiler and runtime failed to prevent it. Erasure is largely to blame.

```
public static RuntimeException sneakyThrow(Throwable t)
{
    throw Util.<RuntimeException>sneakyThrow0(t);
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static <T extends Throwable> T sneakyThrow0(Throwable t) throws T
{
    throw (T)t;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a difference between generic types and generic variables/parameters.

A generic type is a type that declares a generic parameter. For example

```
class Generic<T> {}
```

What isn't allowed is a generic type (like above) that also extends `Throwable`.

```
class Generic <T> extends Throwable {} // nono
```

This is expressed in the Java Language Specification, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.2)

> It is a compile-time error if a generic class is a direct or indirect
>   subclass of `Throwable` (§11.1.1).

Generic variables themselves, however, can have any bound, generic or otherwise, as long as it is a reference type.

This

> `X extends Throwable`

means that whatever type is bound (not has bounds) to `X` at compile time must be a subtype of `Throwable`.

> X is already bound in the method signature.

`X` is not bound. The method declares its bounds.

> Will this by any means, solve the generic exception restriction?

No.

> Why not just `extends Throwable`, as the rest will be erased by type erasure?

Generics are a compile time feature. Erasure happens after compilation. I believe they could have simply used

```
Supplier<? extends Throwable>
```

as the parameter type. But then you'd lose the type variable for use in the `throws` clause.

Post-edit:

> Why not just `throws Throwable`, as the rest will be erased by type erasure?

You want the `throws` to use the same `Exception` type that the `Supplier` supplies.

> Will this method be required to to be caught in a `catch(Throwable t)` clause?

No/depends. If you bind a checked exception to `X`, then you'll need to handle it some way. Otherwise, no `catch` is "required". But something will/should handle it eventually, even if it is the JVM itself.

Comment: I made a minor typo in my last bullet, please review it.

Comment: And added another question, thereafter

Comment: In my last question I meant to say, maybe it could be caught in a more specific type, according to suppliers provided type.

Comment: @MouseEvent Of course. A `catch(Throwable)` would catch everything. For a checked exception, you could specify the same `Exception` type that you would use as the generic type argument provided for the `Supplier`.