# why type variable is non-reifiable type in java

Tags: java, generics, collections

I'm currently learning java generics and below is a list of types in java that is non-reifiable.

A type is not reifiable if it is one of the following:

• A type variable
(such as `T`)

• A parameterized type with actual parameters
(such as `List<Number>, ArrayList<String>, or Map<String, Integer>`)

• A parameterized type with a bound
(such as `List<? extends Number> or Comparable<? super String>`)

I understand why parameterized type with actual parameter and parameterized type with bound is non-refieable, because after runtime erasure, the only type information left is `List`, but why is type variable (such as `T`) a non-reifiable type? I thought at runtime, after type erasure, `T` would become `Object` (given `T` is an unbound type parameter), so the type information is available.

Is there something wrong with my understanding?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18848885/why-following-types-are-reifiable-non-reifiable-in-java) question's answers answer your question? It deals with the same problem.

Comment: That's exactly what it means. Instead of `T` being reified as the type it represents, it's erased to its upper bound.

Comment: @Ben thanks for the suggestion, i have seen that particular post but was still confused after reading it. And my question is more focused on type parameter, so I guess the questions are similar but not exactly same.

Comment: @Thor yes, I figured, that's why I just suggested it over duping :)

Comment: @shmosel could you please explain it a bit more? what is wrong with the runtime type of the `new T[]` being `Object[]`?

Comment: @Ben thanks for the suggestion. really appreciate it :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Who said anything's wrong?

Comment: @shmosel lets say `T[] t = new T[10];` is legal syntax (i know it is illegal), then the runtime type of `t` would be `Object[]`, which is perfectly valid java syntax, so why is `T` a non-reifiable type and why is `new T[]` illegal syntax?

Comment: I do apologise for the follow up questions if it is hard to understand, I'm simply too confused right now

Comment: It's slightly different. `T[] a = new Foo[0]` is `T[]` at compile time but it is a `Foo[]` at runtime. `Object[] a = new Foo[0]` doesn't work as well. `T` matches *a particular type*, but you shouldn't think that it is matching *any* type of `Object`.

Comment: It's non-reifiable because it's not preserved at runtime. That's what non-reifiable means. As to why `new T[]` is illegal, it's because array types *are* reified, and mixing arrays with generics can cause heap pollution. Consider `T[] t = new T[10]; Object[] o = t; o[0] = 1;`. If you replaced `T` with `String`, this would throw an `ArrayStoreException`. But if `T` is a generic type that gets erased to `Object`, the code would run without error, despite possibly violating generic invariants. You can easily test this by casting an `Object[]` to `T[]`.

Comment: In java you also can't do new T(), because you don't know if T has a parameterless constructor, that's why this is disallowed, because you don't have that type information about T. I could have made that constructor private, for example.

Comment: @POrekhov Nobody mentioned `new T()`.

Comment: @shmosel so what? It is related, I said it as a "by the way" thing, why are you so judgemental all the time?

Comment: @POrekhov Because without making several hundred if not thousand judgments per day a human being cannot survive, let alone function, let alone act as a professional in an intellectually demanding occupation. I first heard that particular nonsense in 1970 and I recognized it then for the arrant BS that it is. Nothing has changed. As for your specific point, the issue of not knowing what `T` actually is because it has been erased at compile time is logically prior to the issue of whether it has a no-args constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/nonReifiableVarargsType.html) state that

> A non-reifiable type does not have **all** of its information available at runtime.

The type of `T` at runtime is `Object` so information is lost. An example of the information that is lost is how an object can be created. Consider this class:

```
public class A {
    private int a;
    public A() {
        a = 5;
    }
}
```

Now look at this *not compiling* code:

```
public class Generic<T> {
    T foo() {
        return new T(); //Compiler Error!
    }
}
```

If this was allowed and you were instantiating a `Generic<A> g = new Generic<>();` and calling `g.foo()`, the constructor of `T` could  not be called, because, at runtime, `T` is only known as `Object`. Therefore, an valid instance of `A` cannot be created and returned. You even cannot be sure which information a constructor of `T` needs. The information how `T` can be constructed is lost.

That is one reason why type parameters must be non-reifiable types.

Answer (score 4):

An object is reifiable when its typing information is not lost at compile time. Some operations are not allowed on non-reifiable objects. For example, we can not do an *instance of.*

Generic types are not reifiable and that's why we can not do such a

```
 List <Conference> instance
```

This would be practical in some cases but we must not forget that the JDK must be backward compatible from one version to another. This constraint explains some limitations in implementations.

A Java type is reifiable if it is represented
completely during execution (without erasure
Of type) :

```
 primitive type
 non-parametric type
 parametric type in which all arguments of type are unbounded jokers (List <?>)
 type "raw" (List)
 table whose type of elements is reifiable
```