# Unable to put Class into a generic Map

Tags: java, generics

Here's a visual of the problem:

[image]

As can be seen from the visual, the IDE is showing a compile-time error to which it does not allow the `class` to be inserted into the Map.

Here's a simplified version:

```java
  @Override
  public <T extends Comparable> void transactPersistentEntityStore(...) {
    Map<Class<T>, ComparableBinding> propertyTypeMap = new HashMap<>();
    propertyTypeMap.put(EmbeddedArrayIterable.class, EmbeddedEntityBinding.BINDING);
    propertyTypeMap.put(EmbeddedEntityIterable.class, EmbeddedEntityBinding.BINDING);
    // ...
  }
```

Even if both `EmbeddedArrayIterable` and `EmbeddedEntityIterable` implements `Comparable`

Am I missing or misunderstanding something on generics?

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify the point of the problem to this code snippet:

```
public <T extends Comparable> void m1(T x) {
  Class<? extends Comparable> x1Class = x.getClass();
  Class<T extends Comparable> x2Class = x.getClass();
}
```

Or even to this:

```
public <T> void m2(T x) {
  Class<?> x1Class = x.getClass();
  Class<T> x2Class = x.getClass();
}
```

The line with the variable `x2Class` has an error in these methods.
This is because the compiler throws away the Generics and thus there is no type T at runtime. T is not reifiable. You cannot obtain the type T at runtime.

Have also a look at this article: [Why following types are reifiable& non-reifiable in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18848885/why-following-types-are-reifiable-non-reifiable-in-java)

Comment: How can the `propertyTypeMap` in my example code be passed down if `T` would not work?

Comment: You can change the map's type to ```Map<Class<? extends Comparable>, ComparableBinding>``` or you can pass the class as a parameter to function ```transactPersistentEntityStore```. Look at the method ```toArray``` of ```java.util.List``` for an example of the second idea.